# SQL syntax for complex search

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-division

I'm trying to figure out how to format an SQL SELECT command that will do a complex search

I have a database with two tables.

**Files**
FileID
FilePath

**Parameters**
ParameterName
ParamaterValue
FileID

The goal is to search Parameters for multiple values and then only return FileIDs for those that have all the values.

These are media files so the parameters are things like format, video width, audio codec, etc... I want the user to be able to select as many of these fields as they want and then have it return files that match all of the parameters.

So for example I want to select all the files that have a Format of MKV, a VideoCodec of AVC and and AudioCodec of AAC.

I can't figure out how to do that. If I do a left join I can get it to work with one parameter, but as soon as add a second it fails. I assume I need to use nested joins but I'm not good enough with SQL to figure out exactly how to do that.

This is a local C++ app using SQLite3 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM file
WHERE fileid IN (SELECT fileid FROM parameters WHERE name = 'name1' and value = 'value1') AND
      fileid IN (SELECT fileid FROM parameters WHERE name = 'name2' and value = 'value2') AND 
      fileid IN (SELECT fileid FROM parameters WHERE name = 'name3' and value = 'value3')
```

Comment: I had some weird results from the group method above so I ended up using this method instead.

Answer (score 2):

One method for doing this uses `group by` and `having`:

```
select fileid
from parameters p
where (name = 'name1' and value = 'value1') or
      (name = 'name2' and value = 'value2') or
      (name = 'name3' and value = 'value3')
group by fileid
having count(distinct name) = 3;
```

The "3" is the number of different parameters that you are looking for.

Comment: That does seem to work, but how do I link that into the Files table so I actually get the FilePath for the matching files? I tried using Left Join but it didn't work

Comment: @dan if `SSS` is Gordon's query then `select * from file where fileid in (SSS)` will do the job